# Object Reference Not set to Instance WPF Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, default-constructor

I have already seen the below link

[WPF, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' in Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533539/wpf-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-designer)

My problem is similar but a little different. I am not setting any data context in XAML itself.  I am  creating my own user control and I am using that in another.

```
<usercontrols:MyControl1 x:Name="MyControl1"  Grid.Row="5"  Height="Auto" Width="Auto">

    </usercontrols:MyControl1>
```

This is the code I am using in second control to refer MyControl1. This generally does not throw any exception. But, When I specify some code  in the constructer of MyControl1, the exception is coming. It also says "Cannot Create an Instance of MyControl1".

Comment: are you using any styles to the user control?

Comment: wat code you put in your constructor?

Comment: Creating Instances of some other user controls .. Like     _SampleCOntrol=new MyControl3(Param1);

I am pretty sure that the Param1 will be null before initialization.  Probably that is the issue. But why designer throws error?? I mean it could just ignore it and load control .. no??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this line in MainPage.xaml.cs page

Use the static proeprty DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool to determine if your code is currently being used in a designer tool.

```
InitializeComponent();
if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{
    //Code that throws the exception
}
```

Comment: The Designer was firing my usercontrol loaded event. The code gets a reference to the window it is part of which causes an exception in design mode. Adding this check solved my problem thanks.